# What is the best way to order by parent and child's created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Suppose I have a parent Comment that has many Replies.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :replies

class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :topic
```

I would like to order my Comments by `created_at`, *but* if they have a newer Reply, I would like that parent Comment to be sorted by its most latest Reply's `created_at` and not its own created_at.

So if for example I have 3 Comments, one posted for Day 1, Day 2, and Day 3. Day 1 being the oldest, but Day 2 has a reply that was posted today, how can I sort it so that the result would be :

```
[ Day 2, Day 3, Day 1 ]
```

Where Day 2 has had the *the most recent activity*, more recent than the Day 3 comment that would have been posted earlier in the day.

What would be the approach for that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was a "show us your work so far" type of downvote. I took the liberty to reword your question's last sentence so it doesn't look like you're just asking for someone to write your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling the dates is best done through your models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies
end

class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment, touch: true
end
```

Note the `touch: true` on the `belongs_to: comment` association. This will update the `updated_at` attribute of the parent `Comment` when saving a `Reply`

Now just order by `updated_at` when selecting your comments.

Comment: Do be aware that this approach means every reply will take a lock on the comment being replied to that lasts until the transaction commits. So you can have at most one tx affecting any given comment at a time. That might be OK, but when taking this kind of approach should also be considered. Child updates locking parents can also expose deadlock risks.

Comment: I think in this situation that lock will be almost unnoticeable. If it takes a substantial amount of time to save the reply record then something is terribly wrong. Also, any further updates to the comment row will simply be queued for a tiny amount of time, not blocked completely.

Comment: Sure, waiters only block until the lock holding tx commits. It's really only an issue when you're following this kind of strategy up a tree to a contended resource, you get heavy bursts of activity on one parent object, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The best query for that (as in the one that will perform best) is to add an extra `last_activity` column. Maintain the latter (automatically, using triggers or some RoR built-in sugar) and add an index on it. You'll then be able to fetch rows ordered by that column using trivial queries.

The alternative option is an ugly join with an aggregate (see the answer from an hour ago). It won't be pretty and it will perform *terribly* as your table grows in size.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine something like this might be "okay", but check out the query plan. (I only deal with LINQ and SQL Server myself - YMMV.)

```
select * from comments c 
left join (select r.comment_id, max(r.created_at) as created_at
           from replies r
           group by r.comment_id) lr
on lr.comment_id = c.comment_id
order by isnull(lr.created_at, c.created_at) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

After a `LEFT JOIN` to the latest response (which may not exist, hence the `LEFT`), use (SQL standard) [**`COALESCE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in `ORDER BY`. But only `SELECT` columns from `comments`, according to your requirement:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   comments c 
LEFT   JOIN  (
   SELECT comment_id, max(created_at) AS created_at
   FROM   replies
   GROUP  BY 1
  ) r USING (comment_id)
ORDER  BY COALESCE(r.created_at, c.created_at) DESC
```

Since logic dictates that replies must come after comments. If that wasn't so, you'd use `GREATEST(r.created_at, c.created_at)` instead.